# Android remove Activity observer from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have MVVM single Activity Application with task running every x min.

In `Activity` I'm observing result of that task. Everything works fine.

After navigation to certain `Fragment` I'd like to stop observing it in `Activity` and after navigation to another `Fragment` observe it again (in Activity).

Code for observing in Activity

```
    settingsViewModel.pb.observe(this, Observer {
        pb.visible(it)
    })
```

Hope I made question clear enough

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is

```
  override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    viewModel.request.removeObservers(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead of changing an observer, just observe on Activity and if that fragment is visible just update it from Activity. Something like:

```
settingsViewModel.pb.observe(this, Observer {
        if (currentFrag is yourFragment) {
            // currentFrag.doSomething()
        } else {
            pb.visible(it)
        }
    })
```

Edit 1:

Take a look at primaryNavigationFragment property of your nav fragment, you can get a reference to it there:

```
val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_nav_fragment)
    navHost?.let { navFragment ->
        navFragment.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment?.let {currentFrag->
                // currentFrag.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have `NavHostFragment` in that `Activity`. How can I get `currentFrag`?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove your all observers of your activity life cycle

```
settingsViewModel.pb.removeObservers(mActivity)
```

it will remove all observers of that live data.and when move to another fragment again you can set new observer like you are doing

```
settingsViewModel.pb.observe(this, Observer {
        pb.visible(it)
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

First use [`SharedViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) to have your view model in all of your fragments , and observe your live data in each fragment you need.
Then call your activity method when `livedata` observed.

```
fragment1 {
    sharedViewModel.pb.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        activityCallBack.someMethod()
    })
}

fragment2 {
    sharedViewModel.pb.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        activityCallBack.someMethod()
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm using it like this. But my question is how to stop observing it once I navigate to certain `Fragment`

Comment: @solaza : i don't understand your point. when you navigate to fragment 2, the fragment1 is not in view. thus Livedata in fragment1 does not observed anymore.

just there is a best practice to use 'viewLifecycleOwner' instead of 'this' in observing a live data in fragment. this is because of detaching fragment scenarios.